# close function not being recognized - C++

Tags: c++, c, unix

I have the following piece of code in a file called `RaftLog.cc`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>



namespace LogCabin {
namespace Server {
namespace RaftConsensusInternal {

namespace FilesystemUtil = Storage::FilesystemUtil;

namespace {
bool
fileToProto(const std::string& path, google::protobuf::Message& out)
{
    int fd = open(path.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        return false;
    else
        close(fd);
    FilesystemUtil::FileContents file(path);

        // more code down here, not useful to the problem.
```

However, when I compile I have:

```
build/Server/RaftLog.cc: In function ‘bool LogCabin::Server::RaftConsensusInternal::{anonymous}::fileToProto(const string&, google::protobuf::Message&)’:
build/Server/RaftLog.cc:43:17: error: ‘close’ was not declared in this scope
build/Server/RaftLog.cc: In function ‘void LogCabin::Server::RaftConsensusInternal::{anonymous}::protoToFile(google::protobuf::Message&, const string&)’:
build/Server/RaftLog.cc:76:13: error: ‘close’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ./Server/RaftConsensus.h:17:0,
```

I don't know why the `close()` function does not get included by `#include <fcntl.h>`. May someone please help me? Also let me know if I should include more code.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to include [`unistd.h`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/close) header file if you call `close` function

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Use `fopen/fclose`, `fdopen/close` pair

Comment: Just that? should I also replace `close` by `fclose`?

Comment: Only if you also replace `open` with `fopen` and rewrite the rest of your logic to work with a `FILE*`

Comment: This highlights one of my long standing nits:  `open` is defined in `fcntl.h` but it's "opposite" `close` is defined in `unistd.h`.  I wonder what POSIX's "rationale" section has to say about this.

Comment: @CraigEstey to me this makes sense, as `close` doesn't exactly have the opposite effect of `open`. `open` creates both a file description and a file descriptor for a file. Whereas `close` might only release the file descriptor, but not necessarily the file description. Basically, `close` can be used with all file descriptors (sockets, pipes, files) whereas `open` is the specialized function for creating descriptors for regular files, just like `socket` and `pipe` would be for their respective non regular files.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015

```
#include <corecrt_io.h>
```

seem to work!

Comment: Question didn't mention VS.